# ssh user@localhost vs user@servername

Tags: linux, ssh, redhat

I am working with 2 servers (Redhat enterprise 7). When i ssh both of them. One is showing `user@localhost` where the other is showing `user@servername`.
I would expect to have both like `user@servername`
Any idea?

Comment: Give the server a different name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the output of

```
hostnamectl status
```

then make adjustments to the hostname as appropriate using the [hostnamectl](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec_Configuring_Host_Names_Using_hostnamectl.html) utility.

Answer (score 0):

Check the contents of `/etc/hosts`, it could be that it has the server name as an alias for localhost.